# calling rest api after dataweaver component of mule

Tags: rest, mule, dataweave

I have an api which accepts a json payload.
I am calling this api just after the data weaver component of mule where I am building this json payload.

Answer (score 0):

this just means that the API you are calling is answering with a 500 Internal Server error and the exception is throw becouse the http requester is configured to do so. If you don't want to throw the exception and just continue with the execution even when a 500 error is returned you can add the code 500 the the property "Success Status Code Validator":

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration"  path="/" method="GET"> 
   <http:success-status-code-validator values="200, 201, 500"/>
</http:request>
```